# Copy and Paste row under specific column Heading VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I have code that is copying and pasting rows where the column "A" numbers on the "Data" sheet are found on the "Exceptions" sheet in columns A,B or C.

As of now they are pasting as last rows on the sheet, however Im wondering if theres a way to modify my code so they paste under the corresponding header from the "Exceptions" sheet.

***Example 1:*** Numbers 456, 678 rows should be copied under the "A" Description header on the "Data" sheet since 456, 678 are labeled as "Move to A" on the "Exceptions" sheet.

***Example 2:*** Number 123 row should be copied under the "B" Description header since labeled "Move to B" on "Exceptions" sheet

***Example 3:*** Numbers 345 should be copied under the "C" description header on "Data" sheet since labled "Move to C" on the "Exceptions" sheet.

```
Sub CopyRow()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim Data As String
Dim Exceptions As String

Data = "Data" 'Sheet name
Exceptions = "Exceptions" 'Sheet name
lastRow = Sheets(Data).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For lRow = 2 To lastRow 'Loop through all rows

If Application.CountIf(Sheets(Exceptions).Columns("A"), Sheets(Data).Cells(lRow, "A").Value2) > 0 Then
 Sheets(Data).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value = Sheets(Data).Rows(lRow).Value2
 End If
If Application.CountIf(Sheets(Exceptions).Columns("B"), Sheets(Data).Cells(lRow, "A").Value2) > 0 Then
 Sheets(Data).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value = Sheets(Data).Rows(lRow).Value2
End If
If Application.CountIf(Sheets(Exceptions).Columns("C"), Sheets(Data).Cells(lRow, "A").Value2) > 0 Then
 Sheets(Data).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value = Sheets(Data).Rows(lRow).Value2
End If

Next lRow

End Sub
```

**Data Sheet (Before)**

[image]

**Exceptions Sheet**

[image]

**Data Sheet (After)**

[[image]

Comment: A "before" and "after" screenshot comparison of the Data sheet would clarify what your code is meant to do.  Right now it's not that clear.

Comment: @TimWilliams forgot to add, should be up now

Comment: Isn't your "exceptions" sheet redundant though?  The information needed to re-arrange the data is all on "Data" ?

Comment: @TimWilliams no, will need to go through the Exceptions sheet - I filled in the descriptions just so I could verify it copied more than one column in the row and so I didnt have to flip back and forth to see where they were supposed to go when writing my code

Comment: So "A Cell", "B Cell" etc would be something else entirely?  Are the "A", "B", "C" exactly as shown?   It's best to show the actual data you're using...

Comment: @TimWilliams unfortunately yes, otherwise I would have done it all within the data sheet

Comment: @TimWilliams "A", 'B", "C" headers are as shown, just the descriptions under them ("A Cell", "B Cell"...) will be changed in time.

Comment: Have you considered adding a column on Data for the "move to" value?  That's going to be much easier to use and to code.

Comment: @TimWilliams Will be getting a weekly prepopulated item sheet with thousands of rows. The "Exceptions" page will be for known sku numbers needing to be recategorized into the new headings. It's been made clear to me they want it going through the "Exceptions" page where a simple macro can be clicked and they can add new sku numbers to the "Move to A", "Move to B", "Move to C", category columns whenever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feels a bit clunky, but try this out:

```vb
Sub MoveRows()

    Dim wsD As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet, r As Long
    Dim rngData As Range, rngEx As Range, mH, mR, col As Long, hdr, v
    Dim rngCopy As Range, lr As Long, addr
    
    Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exceptions")
    
    Set rngData = wsD.Range("A2:B" & wsD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For col = 1 To 3  'loop the columns on the exceptions sheet
        lr = wsE.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr > 1 Then
            'get the section header and find on "Data"
            hdr = Replace(wsE.Cells(1, col).Value, "Move to ", "")
            mH = Application.Match(hdr, rngData.Columns(2), 0)
            
            If Not IsError(mH) Then 'matched the header?
                For r = 2 To lr
                    v = wsE.Cells(r, col).Value
                    mR = Application.Match(v, rngData.Columns(1), 0)
                    If Not IsError(mR) Then
                        Set rngCopy = rngData.Rows(mR)
                        rngData.Rows(mH + 1).Insert       'add row below header
                        rngCopy.Copy rngData.Rows(mH + 1) 'copy values
                        rngCopy.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp   'delete source row
                    Else
                        'value was not matched
                        MsgBox "Value '" & v & "' not found on Data sheet!"
                    End If
                Next r
            Else
                'header not matched
                MsgBox "Header '" & hdr & "' not found on data sheet!"
            End If
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: May feel a bit clunky, but that works beautifully well. Thank you so much!